# Save a graph from plotly as pdf

Tags: r, plotly, pdf-generation

How would it be possible to save a graph from plotly into the pdf.

```
fit = qpgraph(f2blocks, graph, return_fstats = TRUE)
fit$score
fit$edges %>% plotly_graph
fit$f4 %>% slice_max(abs(z))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried `pdf()...dev.off()`, `pandoc_convert()`, and `webshot()`, but I failed to produce a pdf file from a `plotly` object.

Then, I check the class of the plotly object. It turns out that the object inherits `htmlwidget` class.

I then used `saveWidget()` from `{htmlwidget}`to save the plotly object as a html file, and then I used `chrome_print` from `{pagedown}` to convert the html file to a pdf file.

Here I use the example in the documentation

```
library(admixtools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(pagedown)

fit = qpgraph(example_f2_blocks, example_graph) 
yourgraph = fit$edges %>% plotly_graph
saveWidget(yourgraph, file = "your_graph.html")
chrome_print("your_graph.html", output = "your_graph.pdf")
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious place where a plot object was assigned a name. Once you have a name, let's say it's named `p` then this is now tested code:

```
library(plotly)
library(reticulate)
py_install("plotly")
p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, type="histogram") 
# without the type parameter the help page example gives warning
reticulate::py_run_string("import sys") # not loaded by default?
reticulate::py_run_string("import plotly") # Also needed?
save_image(p, "./pic.png")
save_image(p, "./pic.pdf")  # checked; both were created

file.show(tmp)  # to see if it succeeded
```

Comment: Hi, I have just installed kaleido. But after running your code have the following error: Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
    File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: I'm guessing its some sort of encoding issue. At seems to happen when expected Unicode versions don't match up with encountered versions. You have not offered a library name for the ploting function and you haven't offered data do there's no way people can do much on encoding errors. You should [edit] your question body to offer a real [MCVE]. Do read both of the cited help pages thoroughly.